# specify bake migration field size - Cake3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Cake3 has a migration wrapper for Phinx. Here is a line to create a table:

```
bin/cake bake migration CreateJobs name:string age:integer
```

CakePHP has docs here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html; however, they do not specify how to limit field sizes.

**Q** How can I specify the size of the field? Am I left to editing the migration file manually?

I'm thinking something like:

```
bin/cake bake migration CreateJobs name:string(100) age:tinyint
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom length values are not supported on the CLI (You may want to [**suggest this as an enhancement**](https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues) over at GitHub), instead a default value based on the type will be used, see

**[github.com/cakephp/migrations/blob/1.1.4/README.md#generating-migrations-from-the-cli](https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/blob/1.1.4/README.md#generating-migrations-from-the-cli)**

> Lengths for certain columns are also defaulted:
>
> - string: 255
> - integer: 11
> - biginteger: 20

So you have to modify the generated files afterwards, or create an extended migration [**shell**](https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/blob/1.1.4/src/Shell/MigrationsShell.php)/[**task**](https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/blob/1.1.4/src/Shell/Task/MigrationTask.php) that uses a [**column parser**](https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/blob/1.1.4/src/Util/ColumnParser.php) that is capable of handling length values.